# Table title without using \caption

Tags: tables

I'd like to give a title to a table. The situation I got is something like the following

[image]

In order to get this I thought I could create a multirow as the first row of the table in which I included the title. Unfortunately this works fine just when the title doesn't exceed the table width: I mean if the title exceeds the table width, using this method, the table will be stretched, like the following one

[image]

What can I do to avoid the table getting stretched? I don't want to use the \caption method cause I will get something like "Table 1.1: TABLE_TITLE", and I don't want that. I'll leave below the code I wrote down for both the tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{TABLE\_TILE}\\
      \hline
      Field0 & Field1 & Filed2\\
      \hline
      value00 & value01 & value02\\
      value10 & value11 & value12\\
      value20 & value21 & value22\\
      \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \\\vspace{1cm}
   \begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{A\_VERY\_VERY\_VERY\_LONG\_TABLE\_TILE}\\
      \hline
      Field0 & Field1 & Filed2\\
      \hline
      value00 & value01 & value02\\
      value10 & value11 & value12\\
      value20 & value21 & value22\\
      \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `caption` package and than write caption as `\caption*{Caption text}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some example of use `\caption*` command defined in the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=sc,justification=RaggedRight}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
   \centering
   \caption*{TABLE TILE}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
      \hline
      Field 0  & Field 1  & Filed 2 \\
      \hline
      value 00 & value 01 & value 02\\
      value 10 & value 11 & value 12\\
      value 20 & value 21 & value 22\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
   \centering
   \caption*{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
      \hline
      Field 0  & Field 1  & Filed 2 \\
      \hline
      value 00 & value 01 & value 02\\
      value 10 & value 11 & value 12\\
      value 20 & value 21 & value 22\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

Caption used in the \verb+threeparttable+:    
    \begin{table}[ht]
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption*{\lipsum[1][3-4]}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
      \hline
      Field 0  & Field 1  & Filed 2 \\
      \hline
      value 00 & value 01 & value 02\\
      value 10 & value 11 & value 12\\
      value 20 & value 21 & value 22\\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

In above examples `caption` doesn't interfere in table width not have marked caption with `Table ...`:

[image]

**Edit:**
As response to your comment.

Using captions has many benefits:

- You define caption properties, if you not like default settings, just once, as is done in above example.
- It works without any settings too.
- Command `\caption` is defined for writing captions, why you not use it?
- For captions, using the package `caption` (or some others) you can simply define properties as font size, font shape and series, formating, space before and after caption etc.
- In the standard  version (with caption label and number) they can be simple referenced in text and collected in list of figures.
- All other solutions , which should serve as captions, don't enable this functionality.
- If you not like captions, than just don't write them. Inserts plain text before or after the tables or stick with your approach showed in question.

Comment: using \caption i should be forced (or am i wrong?) to use the table environment for each tabular and i'm always in touble when i have to set the floating parameters. There's really no other option to make this?

Comment: @frad, you are wrong. You define caption properties , if you not like default settings,  just once, as is done in my answer. It works without this settings too. BTW, `\caption` is defined for writing captions, for which you can define properties as font size, font shape and series, formating, space before and after caption etc. All other solutions not enable this functionality.   In the standard (with labels and numbers) version they can be simple referenced in text and collected in list of figures. If you not like captions, than don't write them. Insert text before/after tables.

Comment: @frad if you don't like floating and want to avoid the `table` environment you can still use @Zarko's approach and use `\captionof*{table}{...}` that is also provided by the `caption` package.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the title outside the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}

TABLE\_TILE

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
  \hline
  Field0 & Field1 & Field2\\
  \hline
  value00 & value01 & value02\\
  value10 & value11 & value12\\
  value20 & value21 & value22\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

A\_VERY\_VERY\_VERY\_LONG\_TABLE\_TILE

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|c}|}
  \hline
  Field0 & Field1 & Field2\\
  \hline
  value00 & value01 & value02\\
  value10 & value11 & value12\\
  value20 & value21 & value22\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]